# Are answers to the Clojure koans posted anywhere?

Tags: clojure

I've been working through the [Clojure koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans), which are great. But there's one problem that I can't figure out what they want. Has anyone posted a set of answers (official or unofficial)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have solved the koans. Indeed they are great.
My solutions can be found at https://github.com/viebel/clojure-koans.

Comment: Ah, I see what they were getting at. Thanks!

Comment: Having a full solution in parallel to the source of the koans themselves is useful, esp. if the road-blocks are qutoes or parens missing etc. Thank You !

Answer (score 20):

Have you looked at the source?

https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/resources/koans.clj

I would think this would work for you, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Taking a quick glance at the source from work... I don't think so. I see what I was looking for in the Y.Sharvit's solutions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since the project has its own testsuite coming with it, where the intended solutions can be looked up.

Comment: That seems as though it would be clear. But for 7: "Functions can also take other functions as input", the answer is listed as * but how does one enter that? #(*) does not work.... Never mind. Just a bare * does work. Thought I had tried it.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this play list, it goes through the tests and gives some insightful explanations

[Learn Clojure - Clojure Koans Walkthrough in Light Table IDE to YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1p6TgkbKXqyOwq6iSkce_EY5YWFHciHt)